# SQL: To Copy data from one column to another in same table by joining and then delete

Tags: sql

I 'm getting errors when I try to copy data from 1 column to another, since there are 2 rows with almost same data but diff unique IDs. I used the select statement which works fine to select the specific dates to be copied to the del_date column from train_date but the condition in where statement. How can I copy the data to the del date and then delete the train_date rows.
Thanks

```
update dbo.Comp d
  set d.del_date =  t.train_date 
  (
   SELECT d.unique_id as delUnique
      ,t.unique_id  as TraUnique
      ,d.del_date as delDelDate
      ,t.del_date as traDelDate
      ,d.train_date as delTrainDt
      ,t.train_date as traTrainDt

  FROM dbo.Comp d 
  inner join dbo.Comp t on d.g_id = t.g_id 
  where t.del_date = d.train_date
  and t.unique_id <> d.unique_id
  order by d.og_id, d.g_id
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using (MySQL, SQL Server)?

Comment: I think I know waht you mean but a bit of example data wouldn't go amiss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
update d
set d.del_date =  t.train_date 
FROM dbo.Comp d 
inner join dbo.Comp t on d.g_id = t.g_id 
where t.del_date = d.train_date
and t.unique_id <> d.unique_id
```

Comment: Thanks, When I use the upper statement I get the following error:

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.

Comment: And if I take off the order by, then it gives me the following error: Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Ambiguous column name 'unique_id'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Ambiguous column name 'unique_id'.

Comment: Remove the order by, i alter the query

Comment: Thanks again, I altered the query by removing order by, but still getting the following error:                                         Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Ambiguous column name 'unique_id'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Ambiguous column name 'unique_id'.

Comment: Strange, you doesn't have to get that error because the line has the table is using **and t.unique_id <> d.unique_id**

Comment: I appreciate your help, I missed the aliases in the unique_id, I used them and looks like its working now.

Comment: Thanks, this is the first time I'm using a blod, can you please guide me how to set it as correct?

Comment: Thanks, this is the first time I'm using a blod, can you please guide me how to set it as correct?

Comment: I meant blog* in the previous comment